# ajax request for real-time monitor

Tags: ajax

We have to monitor the cars of our company which have the GPS installed and draw their position on the map.

We use google map,and render the car with the google.maps.Maker with a custom icon.

Once the position of the car changed,we re-set the position of the marker.

Now we have problems to implement the `real-time`.

In order to make the position of the car real-time we have to refresh the car position in a small interval.

We try to use this kind of solution:

```
function refresh(){
    $.getJSONP(url,'xxx',function(data){
        resetLocation(data);
    }); 
}
setInterval(refresh,delay);
```

Now how to set the delay?

In the clients's opinion,the small the better. Since it will make the car in the map move smoothly. For example,set the delay to 500 mili seconds

However, this will cause the Frequent requests to the server. Can the server and the browser afford this?

Is there a alternative to implement our requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use Websockets or Meteor stream and maintain a connection for a while, if you're going for high resolution updates.

As for whether your server can afford this, that's for you to say. A typical MMO is sending way more data much more often; but they use a data center. So it depends on how much infrastructure you have, how many clients you're expecting, and how much processing the serverside needs to do to compile the data before sending.

It would be advantageous to use an event-based server such as Node.js if you don't have much processing. Even if you do, I'd still serve it from Node or EventMachine, and delegate heavy lifting to other processes.

Look into [socket.io](http://socket.io/) if you're going for Node.

Comment: the  server  is  java  based, and  we  have  to  support  ie 6.  the  clients will  no   more  than  100